# Angular 2 Dropdown Options Default Value without using index

Tags: angular, html-select

How to set a default value , I cannot use index because the default value depends on data.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="task.language" >
  <option *ngFor="let language of languages" [selected]="user.language"  >
      {{language}}
  </option>
</select>
```

"user" is data filled with connected user information (language, firstname, lastname, ...)

Comment: Perhaps this can help you. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4843#issuecomment-206583992

Comment: [ngValue] as specified in this issue  does not work

Comment: What's the purpose of your [(ngModel)]="task.language" in the select element?

Comment: see my comments below I forgot that it was case sensitive.
Wuth the same case [ngValue] works fine thanks

Answer (score 3):

selected is a boolean.
Try this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="task.language" >
  <option *ngFor="let language of languages" [selected]="user.language === language"  >
      {{language}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: That works for me. Maybe I misunderstood. Do you want the selected value of your select element to be the language in 'user.language'? If so, and it doesn't work, make sure you have user populated. You might try 'user?.language === language' instead.

Comment: Afflicted for my prompt response, finally that works.I forgot that it was case sensitive!
before languagues =["nl","fr"] and for instance user.language='NL'
now : languagues =["NL","FR"] and for instance user.language='NL' 
and that works with [selected]="user.language === language"
Thanks